# What is context loader listener in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring Framework and trying to learn spring mvc and spring security frameworks. Can any one please describe me the following that we define in web.xml:

1. Context Loader Listener
2. Dispatcher Servlet

Thanks in advance.
Furqan.

Answer (score 0):

In a Spring Web application you may have two configurations:

The first in which you have a root Application context, that is instantiated by the Context Loader Listener and a second application context let say web application context that is started by Dispatcher Servlet and is a child of root context.

The second in which you don't have a root application context and have only the context instantiated by Dispatcher Servlet.

Say that is clear that if you want two context, root and web you have got listener and dispatcher servlet definitions on your web.xml, otherwise you should have only Dispatcher Servlet definition on your web.xml

I hope that this can help you